# function with quantifier in Z3

Tags: z3

I have a problem with quantifier.

Let a(0) = 0, and a(n+1) would be either a(n)+1 or a(n)+2 based on the value of x(n). We may expect that for any kind of x(.) and for all n, a(n) <= n*2.

Here is the code for Z3:

```
(declare-fun a (Int) Int)
(declare-fun x (Int) Int)
(declare-fun N () Int)
(assert (forall 
    ((n Int))
    (=> (>= n 0)
        (= (a (+ n 1))
            (ite (> (x n) 0)
            (+ (a n) 1)
            (+ (a n) 2)
            )
        )
    )
))
(assert (= (a 0) 0))
(assert (> (a N) (+ N N)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

I hope Z3 could return "unsat", while it always "timeout".
I wonder if Z3 could handle this kind of quantifier, and if somebody could give some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: You need an induction proof to prove your property and Z3 can't do induction proofs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Malte and Nikolaj.
The variable N should be bounded:

```
(assert (> N 0))
(assert (< N 10000))
```

I replace

```
(assert (> (a N) (+ N N)))
```

with

```
(assert (and
 (not (> (a N) (+ N N)))
 (> (a (+ N 1)) (+ (+ N 1) (+ N 1)))
))
```

and it works for both definition of a(n).
Does this a kind of inductive proof as you mentioned?

Here are the two blocks of code, and both of them return "unsat":

```
(declare-fun a (Int) Int)
(declare-fun x (Int) Int)
(declare-fun N () Int)
(assert (forall 
  ((n Int))
    (=> (>= n 0)
        (= (a (+ n 1))
        (ite (> (x n) 0)
        (+ (a n) 1)
        (+ (a n) 2)
        )
    ))
))
(assert (= (a 0) 0))

(assert (> N 0))
(assert (< N 10000))
;(assert (> (a N) (+ N N)))
(assert (and
  (not (> (a N) (+ N N)))
  (> (a (+ N 1)) (+ (+ N 1) (+ N 1)))
))
(check-sat)
;(get-model)
```

and

```
(declare-fun x (Int) Int)
(declare-fun y (Int) Int)
(declare-fun N () Int)

(define-fun-rec a ((n Int)) Int
  (if (> n 0) 
  (if (> (x (- n 1)) 0) (+ (a (- n 1)) 1) (+ (a (- n 1)) 2)) (y n)))
(assert (= (a 0) 0))

(assert (> N 0))
(assert (< N 10000))
;(assert (> (a N) (+ N N)))
(assert (and
  (not (> (a N) (+ N N)))
  (> (a (+ N 1)) (+ (+ N 1) (+ N 1)))
))
(check-sat)
;(get-model)
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your own question? If so, consider accepting it, this is totally fine. If not, please edit your original question instead of using answers to provide additional details or ask follow-up questions.

Answer (score 3):

The formula is SAT, for N < 0, the graph of a is underspecified. 
But the default quantifier instantiation engine can't determine this. You can take advantage of that you are defining a recursive function to enforce a different engine.

```
;(declare-fun a (Int) Int)
 (declare-fun x (Int) Int)
 (declare-fun y (Int) Int)
 (declare-fun N () Int)
 (define-fun-rec a ((n Int)) Int
   (if (> n 0) (if (> (x (- n 1)) 0) (+ (a (- n 1)) 1) (+ (a (- n 1)) 2)) (y n)))
(assert (= (a 0) 0))
(assert (> (a N) (+ N N)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

As Malte writes, there is no support for induction on such formulas so don't expect Z3 to produce induction proofs. It does find inductive invariants on a class of Horn clause formulas, but it requires a transformation to cast arbitrary formulas into this format.

Comment: Thanks, Nikolaj. Would you mind to give a reference about the inductive invariants and the transformation you mentioned?